# Automation Studio fails to load "BR.TechnologyGuarding.Interfaces", "The systeem cannot find the file specified."

Tags: automation, br-automation-studio

B&R Automation Studio(AS) 4.5.2 was working.  I uninstalled previous version of Automation Studio (4.4.4 and 4.3.5).  Now AS 4.5.2 does not load and displays error "Exception at pg"  "Could not load file or assembly'BR.TechnologyGuarding.Interfaces, V1.0.0.0...."
[image: B&R Error Message]

Automation Studio is fully licensed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download from [B&R automation](https://br-automation.com) the latest PVI Manager (Ex: PVI_4.6.2.58_CD.zip).   Run the installation.  During the installation check the Drivers/USB: 1TG500.02 (Technology Guarding) box.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another simple option to fix this problem is to install B&R Technology Guarding again:

- Download the latest version from https://www.br-automation.com/de-at/downloads/software/technology-guarding/technology-guarding/
- Install it

After this I was able to start Automation Studio without any problem.